# Converting String to Array in Node red flow

Tags: node-red

> I am trying to convert a string to a array in Node Red, problem is I already formatted it in an array by using the change node.

E.g. The original data -> "Index:5,125.5,145.2,99.4,47.8"

After using the change node -> [5,125.5,145.2,99.4,47.8]

[image]**This is what is being logged on a .txt file, but when checked through the debug node, it and it still says its a string.**
[image]

I want to convert it into an array so that it can be easier to work with and to put in on the MySQL server in the cloud.

Anything would help!
Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70578310/edit) the question to show how you have configured your change node.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution might be to insert a JSON-node between the change-node and the split-node

Comment: Thank you this solved my problem instantly!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers